# Encoding UTF-8 for Label in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, formatting

I am a beginning iOS developer, and seem to be having some problems with text formatting. Currently I have the following:

```
[self.descriptionLbl setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\nPackage ID: %@" , self.package.Description, self.package.identifier] ];

}else {

    [self.descriptionLbl setText:self.package.Description];

}
```

But if the package description is in a non-english language (French for example) the text is improperly formatted. The French word for developer becomes "dÃ©veloppeur"

I am unsure about how I add UTF-8 formatting to the label above.

For a different app I used

```
content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website.com/file.txt"] 
encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding error: NULL]; Label1.text = content;
```

How would I apply UTF-8 encoding to the first code example?

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is where you fill package description, not where you printing it. Please show as code how you fill it.

Comment: Can you try using, `[self.package.Description stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];`